# Retrieve recent instance of a record within a historical table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```html
How Results Currrently Look Like:
Id:   EmpName:     Date:               Status:
1234 John Doe     2018-12-20 02:00:13.000      Ready To Work
1234 Mary Joe     2018-12-20 02:00:13.000      On Hold
1234 Mary Joe     2019-01-12 15:21:08.000          Delayed
1234 John Doe     2019-01-28 16:32:25.000      Submitted
1234 John Doe     2019-01-28 16:33:01.000      Delayed
1234 John Doe         2019-01-28 16:33:11.000      Submitted
1234 Mary Ann            2019-02-11 12:23:49.000          Completed



How I Want Results to Look Like:
Id: EmployeeName: Date:             Status:
1234 John Doe 2018-12-20 02:00:13.000    Ready To Work
1234 Mary Joe 2018-12-20 02:00:13.000    On Hold
1234 Mary Joe 2019-01-12 15:21:08.000    Delayed
1234 John Doe 2019-01-28 16:33:11.000    Submitted
1234 Mary Ann 2019-02-11 12:23:49.000    Completed
```

Hi All,

I'm trying to create some SQL logic in a history table where it will grab for any Id's if the Status is 'Submitted' and 'Delayed' on the exact same day then I want the most recent instance of it. As shown in the code below: there are 3 rows that pop up for January 28 of that Id being Submitted, Delayed, and then Submitted again. I want just the last instance of the Submission to display in the table along with the rest of the history that ID has associated with it. I'm trying to create logic that applies it to the rest of the table and all other Id's.

I have tried creating a TwentyFourHourInterval column and created logic that states when Date is BETWEEN Date and TwentyFourHourInterval THEN MAX(Date). But that is just pulled the max date which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That one should give you what you want.

```
drop table if exists #t;
create table #t (Id int, EmpName varchar(100), Date datetime, Status varchar(100));

insert into #t values

(1234,  'John Doe',     '2018-12-20 02:00:13.000' ,   'Ready To Work'),
(1234,  'Mary Joe',     '2018-12-20 02:00:13.000'   ,     'On Hold'),
(1234,  'Mary Joe',     '2019-01-12 15:21:08.000'   ,      'Delayed'),
(1234,  'John Doe',     '2019-01-28 16:32:25.000'   ,     'Submitted'),
(1234,  'John Doe',     '2019-01-28 16:33:01.000'   ,     'Delayed'),
(1234,  'John Doe',     '2019-01-28 16:33:11.000'   ,     'Submitted'),
(1234,  'Mary Ann',     '2019-02-11 12:23:49.000'   ,       'Completed');

with t as (
select #t.*,
        case when Status in ('Submitted', 'Delayed') then 1 else 0 end as SubDelFlag,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id, cast(Date as date) 
                            order by case when Status in ('Submitted', 'Delayed') then 1 else 0 end, Date desc) as SubDelRow
from #t)
select Id, EmpName, Date, Status
from t
where SubDelFlag=0 or (SubDelFlag=1 and SubDelRow=1)
```

Comment: This helped answer my question! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

use row_number()

```
 with cte as
 (

 select *,row_number() over(partition by EmpName,cast (date as date) order by date) rn
 from tablename
   ) select * from cte where rn=1
```

Comment: I understand the answer, but this is clearly not correct.  (1) `date` has a time component, so this will return 3 rows for 2019-01-28 and one for 2018-12-20; (2) it does not take into account the status.  (3) I see no requirement on `empname` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

How about just `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.status not in ('Submitted', 'Delayed') or
      t.date = (select max(t2.date)
                from t t2
                where t2.id = t.id and
                      convert(date, t2.date) = convert(date, t.date) and
                      t2.status in ('Submitted', 'Delayed')
               );
```

You *could* do this with `row_number()` although I'm not sure that it is simpler in any sense:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, convert(date, date), (case when status in ('Submitted', 'Delayed') then 1 else 2 end)
                                order by date desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where t.status not in ('Submitted', 'Delayed') or
      t.seqnum = 1;
```